# How can i handle redirecting between ports and suburls

Tags: nginx

I need to handle a not very trivial redirection. Depending on some value i need to redirect user between old pages and new pages. my new pages are published at another port and allocated at another suburl, like:

```
old (port 80):
/goods/browse/
other (port 8080)
/goods/all
```

I need to handle this using nginx features... So i'm trying to make such a config:

```
set $USE_ALTERNATIVE_PAGES 1;
location ~ ^/goods/(.*)$ {

    # 8080
    if ($USE_ALTERNATIVE_PAGES ~* 1) {                          
        return 308 $scheme://$server_name:8080/goods/$;
    }

    # 80
    if ($USE_ALTERNATIVE_PAGES !~* 1){          
        return 308 $scheme://$server_name:80/goods/$;
    }                       
}
```

I think that my config should look somehow like example below.. could anyone help me please how to handle /goods/browse/ or /goods/all redirection in such case? Or how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your situation is quite standard: you want `/goods/browse/` to be proxied to the old server, whereas `/goods/all/` to be proxied to the new server. So you need:

```
location /goods/browse/ {
    proxy_pass http://<server_name_or_IP>;
}
location /goods/all/ {
    proxy_pass http://<server_name_or_IP>:8080;
}
```

I assume the old and new pages are on another machine, since port 80 of the **nginx** host is probably used by **nginx**.

Remark: you probably want to (reverse) proxy the pages instead of redirecting the browser to another URL: the client will not notice that you are using two servers on non standard ports. **nginx** will retrieve the pages for the browser without revealing their location.